# how can i change the search results section when using core spotlight

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, search, spotlight

i've just implement spotlight search in my application
my question is how can i create or change the search result section when searching for some keyword?
now when i type the keyword the result appear on section with my "application bundle name" title and i want that when i type some keyword i will see the result on "APPLICATIONS" section

this is how my code to create search item looks like:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
NSString *prodName = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
NSString *bundleId = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

if (prodName.length == 0)
{
    prodName = @"Casino Lobby";
}

CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *searchableItem = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType: (NSString *)kUTTypePNG];

searchableItem.title = prodName;
searchableItem.contentDescription = OPEN_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_STRING;
searchableItem.creator = prodName;

searchableItem.keywords = [self keyWordForDefaultSearchItems];

CSSearchableItem *item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:nil domainIdentifier:bundleId attributeSet:searchableItem];

return item;
```

[image]